# Like vs. (It's) not like

Tags: expressions, phrase-choice

In the following dialogs are both "like" and "(it's) not like" used correctly in the answers?
If yes, do they both mean the same?
What is the difference if there is one?

> A: She says she's going to help you with your work.
>   B: Like I need her
>   help!

...

> A: She says she's going to help you with your work.
>   B: (It's) not like
>   I need her help!

Is it that "like" contains a bit of sarcasm but "it's not like" doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both are used correctly.  In both cases the "like" could be replaced by "as if".  Both are somewhat colloquial expressions and might not be used by every English speaker.

As you say, the first use is sarcastic, meaning "I really don't need any help from her," with the strong implication that, in fact, she would either be completely unhelpful or possibly that she would make things worse.

The second is much less sarcastic.  It says instead, "I think I can do this without her help." The implication is that you feel someone has challenged your ability to do something and suggested that you might need help from someone.  *"No"*, you respond, *"it's not like I need her help!  I can do it myself."*